# Basic testing NavigationController in Android

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, instrumented-test

I'm currently new to testing, so I decided to start off with some basic stuff.

I handle all my navigations from a **DrawerLayout** that is connected to an **Activity**.

So for my testing I launch an ActivityScenarioRule, create a testNavController object and then I set this testNavController to the current view that handles the navigation (The container fragment).

So the test consists on **opening the drawer**, **clicking on menu item**(Will navigate to a fragment) and therefore **check if navigated to the fragment.**

Then I check if that happened, but the **testNavController stays on the same destination** which is weird because it performs the click, so I decided to **check the navController** *(The real one inside the activity)*, and **it shows me that navigated to the correct fragment.**

Here's the needed code:

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MapsActivityTest {
    @get:Rule
    var activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MapsActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun clickOnDrawerMaps_NavigateToAboutAppFragment() {
        //Create TestNavHostController
        val testNavController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

        UiThreadStatement.runOnUiThread { // This needed because it throws a exception that method addObserver must be called in main thread
            testNavController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        }
        
        val scenario = activityScenarioRule.scenario
        var navcontroller : NavController? = null
        scenario.onActivity {mapsActivity ->
            navcontroller = mapsActivity.navController //Get the real navController just to debug
            mapsActivity.navController = testNavController //Set the test navController
            Navigation.setViewNavController(mapsActivity.binding.containerFragment, testNavController)
        }

        onView(withId(R.id.drawerLayout)).perform(DrawerActions.open()).check(matches(isOpen()))
        onView(withId(R.id.aboutAppFragment)).perform(click())
        assertThat(testNavController.currentDestination?.id).isEqualTo(R.id.aboutAppFragment)
    }
}
```

In the example they use a Fragment, which they set the fragment.requireView() on the launch of the fragment, but I think it's exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `TestNavHostController` at all if your activity already has a real `NavController`?

Comment: My guess when I started testing was to use something "fake" on testing instead of the "real one" just for better practices, but once again I just started with testing and I'm super ignorant! So I guess that we set TestNavController only when using fragments because activity is empty, right? @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `ActivityScenario` (or `ActivityScenarioRule`), your activity is brought all the way up to the resumed state before any `onActivity` calls are made. This means that your real NavController has already been created and used when you call `setupWithNavController`. This is why your call to `setViewNavController()` has no effect.

For these types of integration tests (where you have a real `NavController`), you should not use `TestNavHostController`.

As per the [Test Navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing), `TestNavHostController` is designed for unit tests where you do not have any real `NavController` at all, such as when testing one fragment in isolation.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now! Thank you very much for your explanation :-)